# Find a general solution for $y'=\frac{3x+4y+2}{2x+y+3}$

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, analysis

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{3x+4y+2}{2x+y+3}$$

I tried to solve this problem as following,
like 'exact form problem',

$$(2x+y+3)dy - (3x+4y+2)dx = 0$$

This equation is not exact yet, so i tried to find integrating factor (which make equation into exact form). However, i can't find any factor.

My Question:

1. How to solve this?
2. Is there method using linear transformation ? ( like $3x+4y+2 \rightarrow x$ , $2x+y+3 \rightarrow y$)

Second question is motivated by fact that when we find vloume $(3x+y)^2 + (2x+5) \leq 1$, we can use linear transformation to find vloume by multiplying determinant.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This has the type of a homogeneous ODE. Set $y-b=(x-a)u$ where $a,b$ solve
$$
3a+4b+2=0,\\
2a+b+3=0.
$$
This gives $a=-2$, $b=1$, and
$$
(x+2)u'+u=y'=\frac{3(x+2)+4(y-1)}{2(x+2)+(y-1)}=\frac{3+4u}{2+u},
$$
which is now separable.

---

Or introduce another parameter on the solution curves so that the equation separates into a linear system
$$
\pmatrix{\dot x(t)\\\dot y(t)}
=
\pmatrix{2&1\\3&4}
\pmatrix{x(t)\\y(t)}
+
\pmatrix{3\\2}
$$
with characteristic equation $0=λ^2-6λ+5=(λ-5)(λ-1)$. Left eigenvectors are $(1,1)$ and $(3,-1)$, giving the decoupled equations
$$
(\dot x+\dot y)=5(x+y)+5\\
(3\dot x-\dot y)=(3x-y)+7
$$
which are easy to solve. Then eliminate $t$

Comment: Hi, Thank u very much.. i have question on second method. why we can aussume $dx= 2x+ y+ 3 , dy= 3x+4y+2$?? ( i think it used on matrix)

Comment: Because by introducing $t$ we get an additional degree of freedom that can be used to fix $\frac{dx}{dt}$ to be the denominator term and in consequence get also $\frac{dy}{dt}$ as the numerator.

Comment: Wow, got it! , then how to get the last decoupled equation?  I know what it is eigenvalue and vector and elementary linear algebra. However I cant search that context.

Comment: The left eigenvectors give the linear combinations that decouple the system, the right eigenvectors are a factor in the basis solutions. Usually the solution process uses a basis of right eigenvectors to diagonalize the system, which is to be recommended for larger systems. In dimension 2 or 3 one often can find the solution faster using the above approach.

Comment: How to get this $ \pmatrix{1&1}  \pmatrix{x'\\y'} =  5\pmatrix{1&1}  \pmatrix{x\\y} +5$ .It seems like $v \pmatrix{x'\\y'} =\lambda v  \pmatrix{x\\y}  +5$ ,where $v$ is eigen vector and $\lambda$ is eigen value.

Comment: $(1,1)$ is the left eigenvector to the eigenvalue $5$. Thus the addition of both equations is scalar in $(x+y)$.

Comment: Really Really Thank you . I see now completely, thank you!!

Comment: I have a question to your first approach. When you plug in $y=(x-2)u-1$ into $$\frac{3x+4y+2}{2x+y+3}$$ then how do you get $$\frac{3+4u}{2+u} \, ?$$ Am I missing something?

Comment: Yes, there was a sign mismatch in the first approach which is now corrected.

Answer (score 0):

Let the integrating factor $f$ depend only on $x.$ Then it should satisfy the equation $$2f+2xf'+yf'+3f'=-4f.$$ This simplifies to make $$\frac {f'}{f}=-\frac {6}{2x+y+3},$$ which we may now easily integrate to find a solution $$f=\frac{1}{(3+y+2x)^3}.$$

But this is probably more laborious than the first of the methods suggested by @LutzL above.

Comment: Hi Allawonder, could you explain in detail? I think $(y-2x)(2x+y+3)dy - (y-2x)(3x+4y+2)dx$ is not exact.

Comment: @hew I made an error of omission. I've now essentially rewritten my answer.

Comment: If you assume $f$ depends only $x$, i think the last equation can't be occur.